# -ing verbs after comma

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I need to know if the usage of the gerund form in the following sentence is correct:

The relations between the countries cold due to the piercing statements by the President in 2007, criticizing the party as violent.

I'm translating a text and I have to stick to a specific number of words. Is the previous form correct or shall I say: "in which he criticized the party as violent"?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the complete sentence please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the remarks are in the past, you probably want to use a construction that uses a past tense form of 'criticize' as you mention, i.e. :

"... statements by the President in 2007, which criticized the party as being violent."

Note that I've added "being" to make it more clear that we are applying the adjective to the party's actions, and not the party as an entity.

As well, I might need to see more context, but I suggest also adding a verb earlier in the sentence, or changing the word altogether since 'cold' can't really be a verb on its own.

So, I think a good sentence might be:

"The relations between the countries **turned** cold due to the piercing statements by the President in 2007, which criticized the party as being violent."

or maybe

"The relations between the countries **soured** due to the piercing statements by the President in 2007, which criticized the party as being violent."

It's up to you based on what you feel suits the original text best.